# Functions using new Date() and time

Tags: javascript, function, date, time

I am trying to solve the following:

Create a function that takes the time a person wakes up and the time a person goes to sleep
(yet nothing to do with any particular day). The function should return 3 possible answers.
If the person is not yet awake, return the date and time when they are next awake.
If the person is awake, return now.
If the person has gone to sleep, return the date and time they are next awake.

And here is my code:

```
 function tick(wakey = 8, sleepy = 22) {

    let time = new Date();
    let othertime = new Date();
    let officalwaketime = 8.0;

    time = time.getHours() + ":" + time.getMinutes() + ":" + time.getSeconds();
    if(time < 8.0 || time > 22.0) {
    return wakey + time.toDateString();
    }else if (time >= 8.0 && time <= 22.0) {
    return time;
    }else{
    console.log(officalwaketime);
    console.log(othertime.toDateString());
    }
    }
    console.log(tick(8, 22));
```

Main issue is, that answers are always the same no matter what values are inserted in to console.log(tick(8,22))

Comment: Note that two of your 3 possible answers are the same thing…

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do this:

```js
function tick(wakey = 8, sleepy = 22) {
    const time = new Date();
    const hours = time.getHours();

    return wakey <= hours && hours < sleepy ? time : findNextAwakeDate(time, wakey);

    function findNextAwakeDate(time, wakey) {
        time.setHours(time.getHours() + 1, 0, 0, 0);
        return time.getHours() === wakey ? time : findNextAwakeDate(time, wakey);
    }
}

console.log(tick());
console.log(tick(20, 22));
console.log(tick(2, 5));
```

Comment: Thank you, I will incorporate it into my programming

Comment: The *resetMinutesSecondsMilliseconds* function is unnecessary, you can set them when setting the hours: `time.setHours(time.getHours() + 1, 0, 0, 0)`. Also, `wakey < hours` should be `wakey <= hours` as the person is away at say 8:22 and the function should return the current time.